# Looking for name of a forgotten country band

Tags: ukulele, band

The band never made it very big.  They were comprised of 2 male siblings- 1 was known for a distinctive text tattoo on his (left?) forearm and 2 women who were not related - 1 blonde and 1 brunette.  The band largely broke up because the blonde girl who was known for her ukulele wanted a solo career.

They really only had 1 big music video about going to a big house party.  The CW used their song on one of its young adult dramas.

Comment: Is it bad that my first thought is "the Country Bears"?